# Property 'post' does not exist on type 'HttpClientModule'.ts(2339) ionic4 && angular 7

Tags: ionic4

Property 'post' does not exist on type 'HttpClient'.ts(2339) in ionic4

```
onFormSubmit() {

    let data = 'CardNo=' + '25498' + '&Password=' + '123' + '&DeviceId=' + 'njfngjfg' + '&DeviceType=' + 'android';
this.onFormSubmit = this.http.post('http://dashboard.doit.aw:8081/doit_copy/user2/login', data,

    {
        headers: {
          //'content':"application/json",
          //'content-type':"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
          'Doittoken': "TVRJek5EVWhRQ01r"
        }
    });
    return this.onFormSubmit;

 }
```

post method getting error

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is use HttpClientModule  in your component for making http call.that is wrong

You need to use HttpClient not HttpClientModule to make an http request.

In app.module.ts, import HttpClientModule (see "imports" below):

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
@NgModule({
    imports: [
          HttpClientModule,
    ...
    ],
    ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then, import HttpClient in app.component.ts:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Now, change your AppComponent  from

```
constructor(private http: HttpClientModule){};
```

to

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient){};
```

Comment: Please mark answer as correct if it solved your problem.